# How do I align the "Dernocua" img with the navbar options (txt), which in this case is below it?

Tags: html, css, web, navbar

I want to create a navbar with the name of the store. For a project of a course, I managed to make the navbar work, I just need to place its elements. However, the name of the store is written as in its logo, so it is an image (shrunk by code). I am having difficulty getting the text to be aligned in the middle with the image. As a result, I am left with the image and the navigation words below it, which I cannot center in the middle of the navbar.

Thanks for your help

Btw, the course staff said that I cant use flex.

Im Argentinian, so thats why some comments are in spanish

html code

```html
    <header> 
        <div class="navbar"><!-- Menú de Nav --> 
            <a href="index.html" class="Logo"><img src="./Img/Solo letras.png" alt="Nombre Dernocua"></a>
            <nav> 
                <ul class="Links">
                    <li><a href="./pages/Contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./pages/Nosotros.html">Nosotros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./pages/Productos.html">Productos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="./pages/Ubicación.html">Ubicación</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Css code

```css
/* Controla tam img */
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

/* header (navbar) */
.Logo {
    display: block;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background-color: #DDA15E;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}

.Links a {
    align-items: center;
    color: #283618;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0px 30px;
    transition: all .50s ease;
}

.Links li {
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.Links a:hover {
    text-shadow: #283618 1px 1px;
    color: #ff7b08;
```

I tried everything I know.
Vertical aling: center
top: #px
left: #px

I dont remember everything, bcs Im stuck in this part since yesterday.
I was hoping to have the img on the side, as it is positioned at the moment. And align the navbar options in the center. Their location would be secondary, but I was also hoping to put them in the middle of the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) for this, it is as simple as that.

```
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* flex property for vertical alignment */
}
```

Comment: yeah, I know that is so simple. But the staff Idk why, said that to deliver the first stage of the project. We cannot use flexbox. Bcs they are going to show us, how to use it later. I put it on the question, "Btw, the course staff said that I cant use flex."